# Create one query statement out of two queries?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make one query out of these to queries.In first query I am trying to get sum of articles on different warehouses. In second query I am getting the article trade (how many articles are sold). I want to make one query which will connect these two queries and print results in table.

Query 1

```
SELECT a.ArtId, a.ArtSifra, a.ArtNaziv,a.ArtRoditelj, a.ArtStanjeSA, a.ArtKategorija, a.ArtMjera, sum(b.artpaletatrenutnostanje) as suma, (a.artstanjesa + sum(b.artpaletatrenutnostanje))
          AS ukupno, c.JmOznaka FROM artikli a 
          LEFT JOIN artikli_palete_ulaz b 
          on a.ArtID = b.ArtPaletaArtikal 
          LEFT JOIN jedmj c 
          ON a.ArtMjera = c.JmId
          WHERE a.ArtRoditelj != 0 AND a.ArtAktivan != 0
          GROUP BY a.ArtId ORDER BY a.ArtId asc, a.ArtKategorija asc
```

Query 2

```
SELECT a.Artikal,a.datum,b.ArtNaziv,b.ArtSifra,b.ArtMjera,c.JmNaziv,a.VrstaDokumenta, sum(a.Izlaz) as suma 
FROM kartica_artikla_2015 a 
LEFT JOIN artikli b on a.artikal = b.ArtId 
LEFT JOIN jedmj c ON b.ArtMjera = c.jmid 
WHERE a.VrstaDokumenta != 18 
GROUP BY Artikal
```

These queries works independently.
I was wondering is it possible to connect these two queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.ArtId, a.ArtSifra, a.ArtNaziv,a.ArtRoditelj, a.ArtStanje, a.ArtKategorija,
k.Artikal,k.datum,a.ArtNaziv,a.ArtSifra,a.ArtMjera,c.JmNaziv,
k.VrstaDokumenta, sum(k.Izlaz) as suma
FROM artikli a 
LEFT JOIN kartica_artikla_2015 k on k.artikal = a.ArtId 
LEFT JOIN artikli_palete_ulaz b on a.ArtID = b.ArtPaletaArtikal 
LEFT JOIN jedmj c  ON a.ArtMjera = c.JmId
WHERE a.ArtRoditelj != 0 AND a.ArtAktivan != 0 AND a.VrstaDokumenta != 18
GROUP BY a.ArtId, k.Artikal
ORDER BY a.ArtId asc, a.ArtKategorija asc
```

Comment: I am sorry i put wrong first query but I have tried to make query like that I get wrong values in sum.

Comment: @user3651819:- I have made the JOINS. You just need to put(*add/modify*) the columns in the SELECT statement.

Comment: It does not work, it does not give good results for sum column